# Three20 monotouch/btouch examples?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, three20

Does anyone know of any examples or tutorials working with the three20 btouch dll?

#### Update:

I've basically run btouch against the non-parser three20.cs in the trunk and taken the resulting dll and referenced it in my project.

I've then compiled the three20 stuff in XCode and taken the libThree20.a file and put it in my project.

I've also added the correct mtouch args to the project options.

How can I test that this is all Ok?

Comment: Closing this as you answered your own question by providing a single external link. Happy to re-open if you expand your answer to at least summarize the contents of the blog post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a blog post about this

http://iwayneo.blogspot.com/2010/04/three20-with-monotouch.html

w://